# Google Drive returns 503 Error when uploading a file with non-ASCII title

Tags: title, non-ascii-characters, http-status-code-503

Recently our app tries to upload a file to Google Drive, the server have started returning 503 (Service unavailable) error.
We looked into the problem and have found out that if the note title is written in ascii, the error won't occurred but Korean, Japanese, Chinese includes Russian, all of them ends with the same error. Of course.
Why this is occurring and how to resolve this?